# 2 Player Rock Paper Scissors (Python)

Tags: python, rock-paper-scissors

I created a "2-player" rock-paper-scissors game in Python mainly using if statements and a single while loop. The program is really simple, but I was wondering if using switch statements or perhaps another format would make it less cluttered/quicker/etc.

```
again = 'y'

while (again == 'y'):

    p1 = input("Player 1 --> Rock, Paper, or Scissors? ")
    p1 = p1.lower()

    print()

    p2 = input("Player 2 --> Rock, Paper, or Scissors? ")
    p2 = p2.lower()

    print()

    if (p1 == "rock"):
        if (p2 == "rock"):
            print("The game is a draw")
        elif (p2 == "paper"):
            print("Player 2 wins!")
        elif (p2 == "scissors"):
            print("Player 1 wins!")
    elif (p1 == "paper"):
        if (p2 == "rock"):
            print("Player 1 wins!")
        elif (p2 == "paper"):
            print("The game is a draw")
        elif (p2 == "scissors"):
            print("Player 2 wins!")
    elif (p1 == "scissors"):
        if (p2 == "rock"):
            print("Player 2 wins!")
        elif (p2 == "paper"):
            print("Player 1 wins!")
        elif (p2 == "scissors"):
            print("The game is a draw")
    else:
        print("Invalid input, try again")

    again = input("Type y to play again, anything else to stop: ")

    print()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Remove Redundant Parenthesis

In this line:

```
while (again == 'y'):
```

The parenthesis are unneeded and can (should) be removed.

#### Use a dict to drive the stacked if/else

Whenever I see a stacked if/else I look to restructure the code using a dict (mapping) instead.
The net results of the if/else structure in your code can be put into a dict like so:

```
results = {
    "rock": {
        "rock": "The game is a draw",
        "paper": "Player 2 wins!",
        "scissors": "Player 1 wins!",
    },
    "paper": {
        "rock": "Player 1 wins!",
        "paper": "The game is a draw",
        "scissors": "Player 2 wins!",
    },
    "scissors": {
        "rock": "Player 2 wins!",
        "paper": "Player 1 wins!",
        "scissors": "The game is a draw",
    },
}
```

If the `results` are mapped this way, then the interactions with the user becomes more clear and
your loop can simply become:

```
while again == 'y':

    p1 = input("Player 1 --> Rock, Paper, or Scissors? ").lower()
    print()

    p2 = input("Player 2 --> Rock, Paper, or Scissors? ").lower()
    print()

    result = results.get(p1, {}).get(p2, "Invalid input, try again")
    print(result)

    again = input("Type y to play again, anything else to stop: ")
    print()
```

This is an example of separating the UI (User Interface) from the [Business Logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_logic).

Comment: Interesting, I didn't even think about using a dict in this way. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Listing all possible permutations seems to violate the DRY principle. Plus, it is difficult to extend the logic when additional options are added.

For a sorted list of choices, a player wins with a choice preceding player's 2 choice. Using modulus (%) allows cycling through choices:

```
C = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']
R = ['It\'s a draw!', 'Player 1 wins!', 'Player 2 wins!']

again = 'y'

while again.lower() == 'y':
  p1 = input('Player 1 ~~ Rock, Paper, Scissors ~~ choose:' )
  p2 = input('Player 2 ~~ Rock, Paper, Scissors ~~ choose:' )

  winner = (len(C) + (C.index(p1.lower()) - C.index(p2.lower()))) % len(C)
  
  print(R[winner])
  again = input('Play again [Y]:')
```

Comment: `winner = C.index(p1.lower()) - C.index(p2.lower())` would work as well.

Comment: I'm impressed how short this solution is, very useful - I'll keep this structure in mind